# Adding token to httpheaderfield and escape character passing through

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutableurlrequest

I have a token which contains \" in the string. When i print this string, the slash doesn't appear but quotation mark does. Which is correct.

```
token = "hhgghhgg\"hhgghhgg"
print -> hhgghhgg"hhgghhgg

request.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "API-Token")
```

When i add this token to the header field, the backslash for some reason passes through.

```
print all headers -> API-Token": "hhgghhgg\"hhgghhgg"
```

Im not sure if this is expected behaviour or an error.

Any help will be appreciated

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is correct and this is just some strange `print` behaviour. if you use a playground you can see that everything works as expected.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
token = "hhgghhgg\\\"hhgghhgg"
```

and your result `print(token)`

```
hhgghhgg\"hhgghhgg
```